# How to convert uploaded Excel data to data.frame() code in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one excel file

```
dataA<- read_excel("Yield.xlsx", sheet=1) 
Yield<- dataA %>% as.data.frame() 
Yield
```

[image]

Now, I want to send this data to other people as codes. So, I generated the same data using `data.frame()` by typing one by one.

```
Genotype <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
A<- c(17.0,16.3,16.1,16.3,17.3)
B<- c(36.3,35.4,38.2,36.3,35.2)
C<- c(242.5,237.2,234.3,243.8,232.6)
D<- c(206.4,206.5,206.2,210.9,201.7)
E<- c(70.8,71.2,70.8,73.1,71.9)

Yield2<- data.frame(Genotype,A,B,C,D,E)
```

However, I think there is a way to automatically convert original data (Yield) to data.frame() code to send the data as code, not attached file.

Could you let me know how to do it?

Always many thanks!!

Comment: You could use `dput(Yield)` to convert data to code.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Yield2<-dput(Yield)  This code is perfect!!  Thanks!!

Comment: But, to convert it to code, it's necessary to run dput(Yield), and copy all codes, The code would be the data code.

Comment: You can save the output of dput as a text file, or copy / paste it into a document